# xarray - find data that is not 0 in a multi-dimensional xarray object with massive data efficiently

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, python-xarray

My DataArray object is as below:

```
print(da_criteria_1or0_hourly)

<xarray.DataArray (time: 8760, latitude: 106, longitude: 193)>
dask.array<shape=(8760, 106, 193), dtype=int32, chunksize=(744, 106, 193)>
Coordinates:
  * latitude   (latitude) float32 -39.2 -39.149525 ... -33.950478 -33.9
  * longitude  (longitude) float32 140.8 140.84792 140.89584 ... 149.95209 150.0
  * time       (time) datetime64[ns] 2017-01-01 ... 2017-12-31T23:00:00
```

The data can be either 0 or 1. The number of data is massive (179212080).

I want to get the time, latitude and longitude that meets the criteria of "data == 1".

I was trying to use the .sel function but it was extremely slow due to large number of comparisons.

```
for time_elem in da_criteria_1or0_hourly.coords['time'].values:
    for lat_elem in da_criteria_1or0_hourly.coords['latitude'].values:
        for lon_elem in da_criteria_1or0_hourly.coords['longitude'].values:
            val = da_criteria_1or0_hourly.sel(time=time_elem,latitude=lat_elem,longitude=lon_elem).values
            if (val == 1):
                print(time_elem, lat_elem, lon_elem, val)
```

Is there any more efficient way?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at the `stack` function. It stacks the xarray with all entries below each other and you then might be able to filter for all values that do not meet your requirements. I have not tested it with a super large data-set, but it does not use a triple for-loop, so might give you some speed boost.

The code structure would look like:

```
    newArr = da_criteria_1or0_hourly.stack(z=('time','latitude','longitude'))
    newArr2 = newArr[newArr.values ==1]
```

Then the newArr would be your old array stacked and the newArr2 would contain only your data = 1 observations and should still contain your coordinates (although maybe in a messy format).

Comment: Thanks @seulberg1. I tried the stack method as you pointed out, but unfortunately it seemed to have taken forever to do the stack and memory usage was massive...